# Need to ensure validate server identity is disabled using wpa_supplicant

Tags: 16.04, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect a kiosk type system running 16.04 and wpa-supplicant to an WPA Enterprise wifi network. At other sites I have just been able to use a network service name and password that they have provided.

At this new site, they say they use certificates to validate client authentication, and are telling me to either set my system to ignore when their server sends the certificate or import their certificates, otherwise my system will not authenticate.  They are saying that right now my system never responds after they send the certificate, so the connection times out without connecting.

Reading the wpa-supplicant documentation I am not seeing what setting I need to set to either ingnore their certificate or import it.

My normal config file looks like this:

network={
ssid="XXXXXXXXX"
password="XXXXXXXXX"
identity="XXXXXXXXX"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
eap=PEAP
phase1="peapver=0"
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
scan_ssid=1
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do know that 16.04 is EOL in April of this year and will not receive any more updates or support past that time.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that the problem is the OS version I am using? If I upgraed to 20.04 would the certificate authentication work?

Comment: No I was not mind you it may was just reminding you support will end in April

Comment: Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a little bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19545/43926